# What is the delta from Redis 2.8 to 3.x?

Tags: redis

We have run redis 2.6 (and now 2.8) for some time with good success.

Looking at 3.2, I have not spotted a migration document.

Can you suggest where to find a doc describing new/dropped/changed commands and other migration topics. I could not put a finger on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most significant change between 3.x and 2.x is that since Redis 3.x, it supports [cluster mode](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

You can get other change lists from [Redis 3.2 release note](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.2/00-RELEASENOTES) and [Redis 3.0 release note](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.0/00-RELEASENOTES).